# Throwing Number Format Exception for input String "type" Custom List View

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have tried the below code in Custom List View.I tried to replace Call type with "Incoming","Outgoing" and "missed" it is showing Number Format Exception: For Input String "type"

```
assert cr != null;
if (cr.moveToLast()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cr.getCount(); i++) {
        CallLogData cons = new CallLogData();

        cons.setNumber(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls. NUMBER)));
        cons.setType(cr.getString( cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls. TYPE)));
        callsListView.add(cons);

        cr.moveToPrevious();
    }

    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(getString(Integer.parseInt(CallLog.Calls. TYPE)));
    switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }

        sb.append("\n  ").append(dir);

    }
cr.close();
```

This line where i am getting an error

```
 int dircode = Integer.parseInt(getString(Integer.parseInt(CallLog.Calls. TYPE)));
```

Comment: I'd bet that `CallLog.Calls. TYPE` is the string `"type"`, so `Integer.parseInt("type")` throws exception. Perhaps the second `Integer.parseInt` call in that line should be removed?

Comment: yes CallLog.Call.Type is the string"type" . I have tried by removing second Integer.parseInt but it is showing an error

Comment: Can you try this `int dircode = Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));` ?

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @yoyohoney What's the error?.

Comment: I have tried as u have shown it is showing the same error as Number format exception

Answer (score 1):

[`CallLog.Calls.TYPE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#TYPE) is a column name, not an integer, so it cannot be parsed as one.

According to this line, your database is holding a string for the type, as well, not a number.

```
cons.setType(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));
```

If you want `CallLogData` to store the string value of the type, you should move the switch case up and maybe use `getInt` from the database instead, since that is what it appears that the type is... Although, you should refer to your `CREATE TABLE` statement to verify that.

```
if (cr.moveToLast()) {
    int numIdx = cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int typeIdx = cr.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

    for (int i = 0; i < cr.getCount(); i++) {
        CallLogData cons = new CallLogData();
        cons.setNumber(cr.getString(numIdx));

        String type;
        int callType = cr.getInt(typeIdx);
        switch (callType) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                type = "OUTGOING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                type = "INCOMING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                type = "MISSED";
                break;
            default:
                type = "UNKNOWN";
        }
        cons.setType(type);
    }
```

If the database column really is a string, then you'd want this

```
Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(typeIdx));
```

Also, if you've inserted/created database values yourself, then you could change the type integer to a string value then instead of at query time.

Comment: it is showing an error on this Line  cons.setType(type);

Comment: Well, I did not test the code, and I don't see your CallLogData class, so what is the error?

Comment: Well, you should probably show your full list adapter code then and add more logging statements to debug the issue... The main point here is that it actually compiled